# laravel 9 how to use Auth::logoutOtherDevices to limit concurrent connections

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-9

I need to limit users to a single login in my Laravel 9 application. The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices) shows how to do this on a password change, though it doesn't say where. I want to do this on login. I found a number of pages showing how to do this using LoginController, but v9 doesn't have a LoginController, so where should I do it?

From the routes in auth.php, it looks like the v9 equivalent is AuthenticatedSessionController. Note that I've added the auth.session middleware as per the documentation.

```
Route::middleware('guest', 'auth.session')->group(function () {
    Route::post('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store']);
});
```

The store method in AuthenticatedSessionController seems like the right place. I added  the Auth command after authentication as below.

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $request->authenticate();
    Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->password);

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

This looks like it should work to me, but I can still log on with the same account on two devices and use both normally.

I've followed this through to the OtherDeviceLogout event, which is definitely being fired, but I don't understand how it works to check if it's doing what it should.

What should I look at next?